# What's the better way to ask the user's input after it fails an "if" check?

Tags: c

I'm currently a beginner in C programming and I'm having doubts about using "goto" to check if the user's string is accepted but I hear a lot of people say "goto" is bad programming.

Currently I'm using "goto" after the "if" check to go back to the "gets" command so the user can type again.

```
    printf("Full Name: ");
NAME:
    gets(name);
    if (strlen(name) == 0)
    {
        printf("Empty name. Try again: ");
        goto NAME;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this other than using "goto" or in this case this is not so bad to use it?

Comment: Ya, don't use `goto`. You need a while loop. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754282/how-to-loop-a-console-app) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Don't use `gets`, which is dangerous and obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`while (strlen(name) == 0)
     gets(name);`

Comment: I think you'll want a `do while` loop. We don't know that `name` contains initialised data before the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scheme you can follow:

```
do
   read input
while input not valid

use input
```

If you want do display an error message you can do this instead:

```
read input

while input not valid
   print msg input not valid
   read input

use input
```

Or this:

```
while true
   read input
   if input valid
      break
   print input not valid

use input
```